# Make a full backup with bb

Tags: linux, backup, python, nfs, python3

I used [Butterfly Backup](https://matteoguadrini.github.io/Butterfly-Backup/) to make incremental backups of an NFS share, with a weekly retention. The command used is the following:

`bb backup --computer srvfs1_1020 --destination /dev/nfs/bck --custom-data /mnt/nfs_share1 --type Unix --retention 7 --log`

But now I need to backup a web server, but instead of an incremental, I have to do all full backups. Can you please me? I can't find the option. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the tool. I can tell you that it would be enough to add a trivial parameter to your command: `--mode Full`. Without this parameter, Butterfly Backup defaults to the Incremental value.

But if I can, I would advise you at this point to do differentials from the first full backup; I'll explain. The difference is this:

```
   +----------+   +----------+   +----------+
   |          |   |          |   |          |
   |   Full   | <-+   Inc.   | <-+   Inc.   |
   |          |   |          |   |          |
   +----------+   +----------+   +----------+

   +----------+   +----------+   +----------+
   |          |   |          |   |          |
   |   Full   | <-+   Dif.   |   |   Dif.   |
   |          |   |          |   |          |
   +----+-----+   +----------+   +----+-----+
        ^                             |
        +-----------------------------+
```

Therefore you should schedule a weekly backup in Full (`--mode Full`) and every other day of differential backups (`--mode Differential`). At this point you should have only the differences from the first full day, and then the second, third ... and so on.

Thus, you should have the optimal situation for your purpose.